# SSH not trying private key id_rsa in gitlab omnibus ssh

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I am trying to login via ssh for git. Everything was working fine with public key previously but somehow gitlab omnibus is asking for password on ssh attempt. Following is the output with -vT flag.

```
OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh_config
debug1: /usr/local/etc/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.channeli.in [172.25.55.201] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<username>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<username>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<username>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<username>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA d8:24:f3:3e:c4:1c:3c:c9:02:4b:0b:8e:cf:d2:bb:ab
debug1: Host 'git.channeli.in' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<username>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<username>/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<username>/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Answer (score 0):

SSH is trying your key:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa
```

but it gets rejected by the server. Make sure you have the same key on the server.

Comment: Shouldn't  there have been a statement like trying private key : .ssh/id_rsa ?

Comment: No. It is a key pair. `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. If the public key is rejected, then the private is not even tried.